# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "ankitj"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

This happens even when the DB user specified in .env file is different. For the record "ankitj" is also the username of my system. I don't understand why this is happening.

Here's the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "ankitj"
    at connection.connect.err (/home/ankitj/Desktop/skillbee/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:128:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/home/ankitj/Desktop/skillbee/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:140:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ankitj/Desktop/skillbee/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:124:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:599:20)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: Do you have dotenv installed and configured? It is most likely your environment variables are not properly loaded.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that you're getting this error using Sequelize with Node.js. I ran into the same error when I had the following:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  }
)
```

I was able to solve the issue by replacing it with [a connection ur](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started):

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/gql", {
  dialect: 'postgres'
  // anything else you want to pass
})
```

where `gql` is the name of `DATABASE` in my `.env` file.

The user "ankitj" executes the command to run the Node script, so the script is trying to connect as that user. I first tried to solve this on the Postgres end by adding a user and granting permissions, but was unable to get that to work--I'd be interested in seeing that solution--but specifying a connection url worked for me.

Comment: It didn't work in my case. But instead wrapping the env variables in quotes did the trick for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This worked in my case. issue might be related to not mentioning the server name (localhost) in the 1st case.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when I was using the default password for the PostgreSQL. Try to change it from the command line as follows.

1. `psql`
2. `\password`

Then Enter a new password and update your `.env` files and that should Work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `process.env` variables I put the actual names but wrapped in quotes (" ") and it's worked.

Comment: That means your issue was unrelated to Sequelize and was due to your misuse of process.env

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error but I solved it by using template strings

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(`${process.env.DB_NAME}`, `${process.env.DB_USER}`, `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when I connect with NodeJS and Postgres SQL. I found a solution. We need to check `db.config.js` file(database config file) and index.js(where u called the `const sequelize = new Sequelize(.......)` properties name is matching or not.

```
// db.config.js
module.exports = {
    user: '******',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: '***********',
    password: '***',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: "postgres", // we need to implement 
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
};

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.database, dbConfig.user, dbConfig.password, {
    host: dbConfig.host,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: dbConfig.pool.max,
        min: dbConfig.pool.min,
        acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
        idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
    },
})
```

Mentioned the above params line as (dbConfig.**database**, dbConfig.**user**, dbConfig.**password**) we need to check with db.config.js file

**Note**: please add dialect properties on the `db.config.js` file.

Now Problem is solved...Thanks

[Console verbiage log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXlLh.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with postgres+docker, and everything in your code looks perfectly fine, and none of the answers are able to solve your issue. You have checked all the sequelize configurations, and there is nothing that can go wrong..

Just go and check if you have postgres service running on your local.
Execute `sudo systemctl stop postgres*` and this would be able to solve your `auth failed` and related Sequelize Error.